# Keep the body input field expanded in the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, asking-questions, android-app

In the android app all the submit question fields shrink to one line each when the keyboard is showing. Pressing back to close the keyboard makes the body field expand so that it takes up the remaining space.

I think it should always be this size as it's very hard to create a question (particularly one that's formatted reasonably as opposed to a single paragraph) using the app while only being able to see a line at a time (unless I close the keyboard, check my text then open it again).

I appreciate I can keep using preview, but think this isn't needed as I should be able to just read more than a few words of my question at a time easily.

I'm on an S2 with SwiftKey if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of a a while back (way before the version 1.0 release) the body input field here is limited to at least 3 lines, and if you type enough into it to make it expand it stays expanded.